# UIDatePicker reflect chosen time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I'm using a UIDatePicker to allow users to choose a time for daily notifications in my app. However, it doesn't keep the value of the chosen time on the actual picker. How would I go about having the UIDatePicker reflect the time that they have chosen?
[Setup of UIDatePicker and Notifications page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwY3L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you store your notification time, but you are responsible for setting the date picker to that time. For instance, here I am setting a picker to show the time exactly seven days ago:

```
let oneWeekAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!
datePicker.setDate(oneWeekAgo, animated: true)
```

Your problem is since you are not saving the UIDatePicker time somewhere other than in the notification itself you are unsure of how to set it back to the UIDatePicker when it comes time to edit it. You could try something like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
    guard let notification = requests.first(where: { $0.identifier == "notInt" }) else { return }
    guard let trigger = notification.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger else { return }
    notificationTime.date = trigger.nextTriggerDate()
}
```

... getting all pending notification requests, finding the one that matches the identifier you set and get the time from that. `notificationTime` above is the UIDatePicker.

Comment: Thank you. Still not able to get it to properly pull the time. Here is what I have under the viewDidLoad of this view controller: `        let timePicker = notificationTime
        let tempDate = timePicker?.date
        
        var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: tempDate!)
        
        let setTime = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
        notificationTime.setDate(setTime!, animated: true)`                -Sorry for formatting issues.

Comment: What's the variable `notificationTime` in your code? From your code here it looks like you're just getting the time from the time picker and setting that same time back onto the time picker? You are not showing where you are getting the time of your notification from.

Comment: I've pasted the code here for both functions in the file: https://pastebin.com/3SahSFFq

Comment: Where would nextTriggerDate need to be defined @Terje

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I corrected the last line in the example.

Comment: Awesome. Only other thing was it gave me "Cannot assign value of type 'Date?' to type 'UIDatePicker!'"   I'm assuming that it's just something I need to convert?

Comment: No, I fixed the last line again. My mistake, but it's really a good idea to name your variables with an indication of what kind of object they are. `notificationTimePicker` would be a better name IMHO.